# Using WebFlux and MVC in the same Spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

Can I use Spring boot WebFlux and Spring MVC in the same application instance

I have 2 classical end point (mvc) and one reactive end point.

I use postgres as my Data base so I want one Service to use JPA associated with the two MVC end point and the reactive end point to use r2dbc to reactive pipeline since it should be more frequently accessed

I use Spring boot 3.0.5

Comment: please clarify your question. What do you mean by the same container?

Comment: I meant same application context or same application instance. I edited the question

Comment: You can not do it because Spring allows only one embedded server to run.

Comment: Can I use Tomcat for both reactive and non reactive end point since it uses servlet 3.1 or above?